# Error:Access to the path 'G:\PleskVhosts\smartheat-eg.net\httpdocs\SolutionsImages\1049sTulips.jpg' is denied. in GoDaddy server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, path

I have hosting on godaddy.com,

I've contacted the support GoDaddy, but there is no solution, this code working in y local machine without any problem

and this is my code for upload images to this path :

```
  if (uploadImageSolution.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                if (uploadImageSolution.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg" ||
                    uploadImageSolution.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/.jpg" ||
                    uploadImageSolution.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/.psd" ||
                    uploadImageSolution.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/.png" ||
                    uploadImageSolution.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/.gif")
                {
                    if (uploadImageSolution.PostedFile.ContentLength < 8100000)
                    {
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(uploadImageSolution.FileName);
                        uploadImageSolution.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SolutionsImages/"+ _ID + "s" + filename));

                    }
                    else
                    {


                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                imgmsg.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you want us to do? You don't have access to that path, only the server owner can grant you that. If they're saying they can't do that then save your images somewhere else.

Comment: i am just check if any advice ?!

Comment: Exactly what I said, get access to the path or save your images elsewhere. Without understanding anything about what you're trying to do then it's hard to be any more specific.

Comment: i created other path or folder to save images and still have the same problem

Comment: This is simple issue. You just need to ask your hosting provider to give full permission for you. It will fix your issue.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so I just worked this issue out with a GoDaddy rep and let me tell you it was not easy.

Here's what you do in Plesk admin panel. Go to the Root directory and put your mouse over your website folder on the right. A tiny arrow shows up on the right of the folder name. <For some reason, I tried to post images into this answer but it's not appearing.>

[Plesk Admin Permission Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnlog.png)

Once you go into that screen it's pretty much self-explanatory. Click the check box for "Replace permission entries on all child objects with the entries displayed here", choose the App Pool Group and add the "Modify" permissions.

[Replace Perms and Select App Pool Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2YM6.png)

[Modify Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEDL0.png)

Then click on the "Ok" button in the bottom and you're ready to go.

That should fix this issue for you.

Comment: Worked for me, life saver.

Comment: Worked for me as well! You sir are a rockstar! Thank You!